# How to compile visual suidop 2019 c# solution from command line w/o opening the IDE on windows?

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line, compilation, msbuild

I want to just build, and output the logs.

Following [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches?view=vs-2019),

> The following command-line switches don't display the IDE.

start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\devenv.exe" "C:\code\EPMD\Kodex\Solutions\Kodex.All.sln" /Rebuild

This does open the IDE.

---

Using

```
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" "C:\code\EPMD\Kodex\Solutions\Kodex.All.sln" /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release
```

also opens the IDE and builds the solution.

---

Doing

```
start "" /WAIT "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /build Release Kodex.All.sln
```

doesn't compile anything (that I know of), and returns immediately, silently.

---

Obviously I am missing some space or options or other trivial detail.

Don't even know how to debug this.

Help please

Comment: `This does open the IDE.` Because (a) you are using `start` but the first quoted argument is taken to be the window title, so either drop `start` or add a dummy `start "title" ...`, and (b) you are specifying the GUI `devenv.exe` instead of the console `devenv.com` or just `devenv`.

Comment: What exactly is that C# project? Calling MSBuild should never pop up Visual Studio for most projects. Try for yourself on a simplest console application project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the examples provided in the below Microsoft Docs link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-specific-targets-in-solutions-by-using-msbuild-exe?view=vs-2019

Check the See Also section documentation as well. Hope this one helps!

Comment: Thanks for the documentation reference.  A better answer be usage demo of the original posters problem.  Something like "Use msbuild to build the solution instead of the start command to open the ide.  For example, msbuild ... and then point to the url for more info.